# Handling HTML (multipart form-data) file uploads with Java

Tags: java, html, jakarta-ee

I'm working on a multiple file upload solution for a proof-of-concept web application.  I'm using a java servlet to handle an AJAX file upload.  My question is how does java handle uploading files from an HTML form?  If someone could explain how a basic HTML file upload is processed then I could probably port this to my solution.

*Quick tangent:*
I'm a web developer with a background in C# & PHP.  I'm trying to hop on the Java bandwagon now that I've taken a new position where mycompany believes Java is the holy grail of all programming languages.  I feel like I'm missing something here... I definitely like the feel of the Java language and how easy it is to run applications.  But its seems infinitely difficult to use as a web programming language.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: There's an Apache project that's a library to do the MIME unpacking etc.  It's an inherently messy problem for *any* server-side environment, but out of the Oracle box Java really doesn't do you any favors. (Really, Java as a web application language really only makes sense once you've picked one of the hundreds of frameworks to build on.)

Comment: [Here](http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/) is the project I was thinking about - personally I use it via the Stripes web framework, which adds its own layer of convenience over that.

Comment: Thanks Pointy.  That's the project I was looking at a couple minutes ago too... being new to the Java scene, I wasn't sure what route to take yet.  I'll check it out further.

Comment: Answer: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2422468/how-to-upload-files-in-jsp-servlet/2424824#2424824

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use **Commons FileUpload** library:

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/

Here is simple example of it's usage:

```
// Create a factory for disk-based file items
FileItemFactory factory = new DiskFileItemFactory();

// Create a new file upload handler
ServletFileUpload upload = new ServletFileUpload(factory);

// Parse the request
List /* FileItem */ items = upload.parseRequest(request);
```

I taken this example from here:

http://commons.apache.org/fileupload/using.html

Answer (score 1):

I just did it today. I followed [this tutorial](http://www.jroller.com/hasant/entry/fileupload_with_gwt). It is specific for [GWT](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/), but author explained basics brilliantly.

Comment: Nice tutorial.  The author is using the same library that pointy suggested above.  I'm going to give it a try.  Many thanks!

Comment: Yes, apache commons are realy 'common' to use :) You'll definitelly write less boilerplate with these libs.